# How to export all failed process sessions?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I use "Advanced Find", but it didn't work, there were just 3 or 4 records which are clearly wrong, should be plenty of records if I step into process and check process sessions manually.
[image]

Comment: How did you get on? Is there still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the Advanced Find that you want:

[image]